# Does random_string function return unique string?

Tags: codeigniter, random

I'm using `random_string('alnum', 10)` function from String Helper available in  Codeigniter 3.0. Does the string returned by function each time remain unique as well? If not then what can I use?

Answer (score 2):

No It does not unique.
As Example

```
random_string('alnum', 1);//if you run this more than 63 you will get minimum one duplicate.
```

For unique you can use

```
random_string('unique');
```

See the [Full documentaion](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/string_helper.html)

Answer (score 0):

As the name suggests the string is *random*. That means with a certain (potentially small) probability this function will return the same string twice.

One way to make create a unique string is to have a counter variable which is not a string but a number. Every time you need a new unique string, you increment the counter and then convert the number to a string.